# Issues with Rendering Shiny Modules Across Different Tabs

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I'm currently working on a Shiny application that utilizes modules to create tables in different tabs. My intent is to render different datasets depending on the selected tab using one module to manage the `DTOutput`. However, I'm encountering some challenges in dynamically calling and rendering the module based on the selected tab. Below is a simplified example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

tableModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("table"))
}

tableModule <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    data()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabModeTransport",
    tabPanel("Mode A", tableModuleUI("modeA")),
    tabPanel("Mode B", tableModuleUI("modeB"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  datasets <- list(
    modeA = mtcars,
    modeB = iris
  )

  observeEvent(input$tabModeTransport, {
    if (input$tabModeTransport == "modeA") {
      callModule(tableModule, "modeA", reactive({datasets$modeA}))
    }
    else if (input$tabModeTransport == "modeB") {
      callModule(tableModule, "modeB", reactive({datasets$modeB}))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

While the above code works in a basic scenario, it seems inefficient, especially when scaling with more tabs and modules, as it requires explicit conditional logic for each tab. I was expecting something more dynamic, where I can render the module for any selected tab without requiring explicit condition checking for each tab.

Here are my questions:

Is there a more efficient approach to manage module calling and rendering for different tabs?

Is it possible to dynamically choose which dataset/module to render based on the active tab without employing multiple conditional checks?

I appreciate any advice or insights into potential solutions or best practices!

Comment: If this works, you could do in one shot: `mode <- input$tabModeTransport  ; callModule(tableModule, mode, reactive({datasets[[mode]]}))`.

Comment: I'd like to clarify that the posted code does not work as desired, which is precisely why I'm seeking help. Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately, it does not work within the context of my current code.

Comment: `input$tabModeTransport` takes the values `"Mode A"` and `"Mode B"`, not `"modeA"` and `"modeB"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the argument `value` in `tabPanel`. Here is the app including this correction as well as the code of my comment, to avoid the `if/else`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

tableModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("table"))
}

tableModule <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    data()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabModeTransport",
    tabPanel("Mode A", tableModuleUI("modeA"), value = "modeA"),
    tabPanel("Mode B", tableModuleUI("modeB"), value = "modeB")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  datasets <- list(
    modeA = mtcars,
    modeB = iris
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$tabModeTransport, {
    mode <- input$tabModeTransport
    callModule(tableModule, mode, reactive(datasets[[mode]]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```